# Organizar bar chart por data

Tags: php, javascript, chartjs

Utilizando o [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart), estou gerando um gráfico em barras comparando entre o mês atual e anterior, o dia e valor do pagamento efetuado. O problema é que os labels tem um range de 1 a 31, os dados do gráfico não acompanham corretamente os valores.

O código abaixo

```
;var chartJS_w0 = new Chart(document.getElementById('w0').getContext('2d')).Bar({
    "labels":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],
    "datasets":{
        "1":{"data":[1600.7500305176,1154.9299926758,6404.6300048828,1609.1199951172,1189.7799987793,386.72999572754,1110.3299942017,720.71999359131,1307.1999816895,12326.089944839,735.86999511719,2125.9599761963,17231.699935913,4276.4899749756,1115.2200012207,5191.6699905396,4281.6599273682,1750,5896.2799987793],

        "fillColor":"#b9ea45",
        "strokeColor":"#0d8cba",
        "highlightFill":"#2d11b2",
        "highlightStroke":"#b153de"},

        "2":{
            "data":[2458.1199874878,1400,679.55999755859,412.92999267578],

            "fillColor":"#d8d59a",
            "strokeColor":"#d2dcfe",
            "highlightFill":"#d4a021",
            "highlightStroke":"#2acbda"
        }
    }
}, {});
```

Gera o gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ele alimenta o gráfico de maneira contínua. Por exemplo: O segundo dataset possui os valores

```
"data":[2458.1199874878,1400,679.55999755859,412.92999267578],
```

E deveriam estar apontados nos labels:

```
"label":["1","2","5","6"]
```

E não 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi percorrer o array **data** e verificar quais os dias que não havia pagamento registrado, atribuindo o valor zero. Fazendo assim que os valores fossem intercalados de acordo com o dia de pagamento:

```
"data":[2458.1199874878,1400, 0, 679.55999755859,412.92999267578 ,0,0,0,0,0,0.....]
```